# Using Web APIs with ArcFM Data

Tags: arcgis-server, web-mapping, flex, arcfm

Has anyone worked with ArcGIS server, when the data is stored in SDE with ArcFM?

While researching this Issue for a friend, I found out that [ArcFM Server](http://www.telvent-gis.com/products/server.shtml) would be needed.
What is not clear, is if a Map can be published, and consumed via Flex or Silverlight API.

Has anyone successfully done something like this? Any pointers would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can access data in a read-only fashion using the ArcFM Object Reader, which is a free download on our website.  Editing ArcFM data requires an ArcFM Server license.  This ensures that business rule logic (i.e. autoupdaters) execute and data integrity is maintained.

Comment: I want read only access, but via the REST end-point, since i want to use it in a flex app. Is that possible.

Comment: Yes. For ready only access via REST or Arcobjects, you need to have ArcFM Object Reader installed on your arcGIS Server machine.  You'll want the 64 bit version since AGS runs as 64 bit.  https://infrastructurecommunity.schneider-electric.com/docs/DOC-2612

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when you have a map referencing data registered with ArcFM (i.e. converted to ArcFM objects), you can publish a map service provided you also have the ArcFM Server installed.

Once a service is successfully published, you can access it via REST and SOAP APIs just like any other plain service.

Comment: I would love to take your word for it, but the person who asked me would be more satisfied with some link or sample ect to show to his boss.

Comment: http://www.telvent-gis.com/products/server.shtml > it works

Comment: Well if you want something more trustworthy, ask Telvent directly, I am sure they will be able to reply promptly. It can't get any more official than their statement.

Comment: You only need ArcFM server (which requires a paid license) if you plan to EDIT features via arcobjects or REST featureservice updatefeatures() etc. methods.  For free, read only access just install the free arcFM object reader.  https://infrastructurecommunity.schneider-electric.com/docs/DOC-7972